# How do I access SourceGear Web services using SOAP::Lite?

Tags: web-services, perl, soap, sourcegear-fortress

For some reason [SourceGear](http://sourcegear.com) provide an undocumented Web service on their installations. They actually ask developers to use the API instead because the Web service is kinda messy, but this is a problem in my case because I cannot use this API on a Perl environment, so their solution for my specific case is to use the Web service.

This shouldn't be a problem. Using [SOAP::Lite](http://p3rl.org/SOAP%3a%3aLite) I have connected to several Web services in the past in the same way. But the lack of documentation is a major chaos if you don't know where the SOAP calls can be made. I only have an XML to decipher where to and how to make these calls. It would be great if a real SOAP genius could help me out in this.

This is an example of the login call and the expected response:

Request

```
POST /fortress/dragnetwebservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: velecloudserver
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.sourcegear.com/schemas/dragnet/LoginPlainText"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LoginPlainText xmlns="http://www.sourcegear.com/schemas/dragnet">
      <strLogin>string</strLogin>
      <strPassword>string</strPassword>
    </LoginPlainText>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LoginPlainTextResponse xmlns="http://www.sourcegear.com/schemas/dragnet">
      <LoginPlainTextResult>int</LoginPlainTextResult>
      <strAuthTicket>string</strAuthTicket>
    </LoginPlainTextResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm looking for a way to be able to assemble this somehow. This is my Perl example:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite -> uri ('http://velecloudserver/fortress/dragnetwebservice.asmx') -> proxy('http://velecloudserver/fortress/dragnetwebservice.asmx/LoginPlainText');
my $som = $soap->call('LoginPlainText', SOAP::Data->name('LoginPlainText')->value(
    \SOAP::Data->value([
        SOAP::Data->name('strLogin')->value( 'admin' ),
        SOAP::Data->name('strPassword')->value('Adm1234'),
    ]))
);
```

Any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by pointing wget/curl/lwp/etc. at http://velecloudserver/fortress/dragnetwebservice.asmx?WSDL
and see if you get a WSDL file back.

If you do, then compare it to the four types listed in the SOAP::Lite POD.
Your Request example looks like the Docment/Literal form, so you might end up writing something like this:

```
  use SOAP::Lite;
  my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new( file => 'http://velecloudserver/fortress/dragnetwebservice.asmx?WSDL');

  $soap->on_action( sub { "urn:dragnetservice#LoginPlainText" });
  $soap->autotype(0);
  $soap->default_ns('urn:LoginPlainText');

  my $som = $soap->call("LoginPlainText",
         SOAP::Data->name('strLogin')->value( 'admin' ),
         SOAP::Data->name('strPassword')->value('Adm1234'),
  );

  die $som->fault->{ faultstring } if ($som->fault);
  print $som->result, "\n";
```

If you don't get WSDL back, I'd try replacing the constructor call with:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new( proxy => 'http://velecloudserver/fortress/dragnetwebservice.asmx');
```

The last time I worked with SOAP::Lite, I wrote a short program similar to the one above, and I ran it under the debugger. Before I executed the $soap->call() line, I peeked at the guts of the $soap object and looked at the request payload to see if the XML matched some  working XML that I had by using the soapUI.org java client.

I had to read the POD a couple of times, and I dug into the source to figure our how some of the methods like default_ns() affected the generated XML.  Once I did that, it all made a lot more sense.

Note: SOAP::Lite likes to die() when it fails. Wrap your calls in an eval{} for production use.

Comment: Thanks the proxy way turns to work just right i only have some issues because the service returns me a 1002 as LoginPlainTextResult and a null value for strAuthTicket i still doesn't know what this means but at least i got a reply.